# App ID Services and Conventions

Tags: ios, iphone, app-id

A few quick questions on App ID's / Submission if you don't mind,

1: Can many App ID's can be added to the same provisioning/distribution profile? - so apps with different app ids can be distributed to the store with the same distribution profile?

2: Can you release an app to the store with a wildcard app id?

3: Does enabling services on an app id just allow you to use for example iCloud apis? If they weren't enabled would iCloud Apis (for example) just be ignored in the app?

4: When I was submitting my app last night, iTunes Connect needed a bundle id, which I set to say "com.John.myApp" -- when I was validating my app it said that my Apps bundle Id in xcode had to match "com.John.myApp" that I set in iTunes connect....

However in xcode my bundle id was something bigger like: "com.John.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}"

so I just set it to "com.John.myApp" is that ok?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a wildcard profile.
2. Yes.
3. It depends on the service, and some services won't work with a wildcard profile.
4. Yes. The default you replaced is just a default, a lot of people will have the app name in the bundle I'd but you don't have to.